# c++ conversion const member

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have a member L that is a list of pairs of ints which I would like to use in a const function. I'm hence not supposed to modify L, but I don't know how I can iterate through L, to read its contents (as opposed to modifying them).

The compiler keeps saying there is a conversion issue.

Comment: Are you looking for `list::const_iterator`? Show some code.

Comment: please show us, what you have tried so far.

Comment: This isn't a question. Nor is it a proper description of the problem you are having.

Comment: What even more sucks than not answering the comments is that you've been on stack overflow just some minutes ago and _ignoring_ the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using `std::list<std::pair<int,int>>` you need to use `std::list<std::pair<int,int>>::const_iterator` as the type for your iterator.